# No option to preview transformation

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web.config-transform

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and at one time I was able to right click on a web.config transformation file and there was a 'Preview Transformation' option that I could click on and see the result of the transform on the file. It is no longer there for any solution I have.

How can I get this option back or is another way to get to the transformation preview?

I did update to Update 3 recently.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else coming to this post I ran into the same issue in VS 2019.  The problem appears to be that the name of the environment in the file name, i.e. `web.<environment>.config` must exist as a **Build** configuration.  Since Release and Debug exist by default when you name your transformation `web.Release.config` the menu option should appear.  If you want to add different transformation file names, Development/Staging/Production, then add new configurations from the **Configuration Manager**.  In this case I'd create three named Development, Staging, and Production.  Once you add those configurations on the project run a Rebuild against it and then right click on the transformation file.  You should see the **Preview Transformation** option near the top of the menu.

Answer (score 1):

I found a Visual Studio extension called [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) that allows me to preview transformations. I am still not sure what happened to Visual Studio's transformation preview, but I can do what I need to now.